# Blazor Login Logging

Tags: authentication, logging, blazor

I have a Blazor wasm hosted app on .net5 with default identity pages. I want to log all login events on the server side. I made a change to the login.cshtml page to 'log' on successful login but that only works if user uses the login page. If the user reopens the browser while she was already logged in, blazor just shows an Authorizing... message and the user get logged in this. I dont know where to catch and log this event. Any ideas? Do I need to tap into IdentityServer4 events of some kind?